# Is it possible to use transaction policies to control API access granularity?

Tags: eventlogfile, shield

I know that the new Salesforce Shield / Apex transaction policies functionality allows monitoring of the events and automatically reacting to them (like automatically suspending accounts with 'suspicious' activity).

Was wondering, as we only have on/off box for API access, can we instead drop certain events using Apex policies by using TxnSecurity.PolicyCondition?

Say I only want users to access one sobject via API, but do not execute SOQL, SOSL, etc.?